# Creating expressions for a different object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a list of expressions for a given object. I need to create matching expressions for a separate object based off of the expressions provided in the list. Currently, I am trying to manually extract the properties from the expression and rebuild a new expression for the other object.

```
foreach(var clause in list)
{
    //this needs to change since not all expressions are binary
    var exp = clause as BinaryExpression;

    var member = exp.Left as MemberExpression;
    var otherObjectMember = Expression.Property(otherObject, member.Member.Name);

    //member does not exist in otherObject
    if (otherObjectMember == null)
        continue;

    //this needs to change to handle other expression types, not only equal
    var otherObjectMemberCheck = Expression.Equal(otherObjectMember, exp.Right);

    //additional processing...
}
```

The above code will work fine with this example list of expressions:

```
entity.Enabled == true
entity.Priority == 1
```

The problem with this is that every expression type scenario must be handled manually (equals, not equals, contains, etc).

The following expressions won't work:

```
entity.Name.Contains("CPU")
values.Contains(entity.Name)
entity.Priority < 5
and any other non-binary expressions
```

I am hoping there is a better way to handle this reassignment of expressions. Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using a simple ExpressionVisitor.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression Target { get; set; } 
    public ParameterExpression Replacement { get; set; } 
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == Target ? Replacement : base.VisitParameter(node);
    } 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = Expression.Variable(typeof(string));
        var item = Expression.Property(obj, "Length");

        var otherObj = Expression.Variable(typeof(string));
        var replacedItem = new Visitor()
        {
            Target = obj, 
            Replacement = otherObj, 
        }.Visit(item);
    }
}
```

The visitor will visit every node in the expression, recursively. When finds a ParameterExpression, it checks to see whether it's the variable we want to replace: if it is, it returns the replacement. The end result is an expression which is the same as the input, but every occurrence of the target variable has been replaced by the replacement.

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising. I am fiddling with the implementation of `ExpressionVisitor` and seeing how I can apply it in my case. It seems like I may instead need to override other methods like `VisitMember`, `VisitMethodCall`, etc. Either way, this seems like a good direction to take.

Comment: You shouldnt need to - when the default VisitMember method is called for example, it will then go onto visit the thing variable method is called on, and any variables pass to the method. Just visiting parameters should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an adapter object that will be used for building expressions . Then, you will have a lambda for that single Adapter object. Adapter should have property Target and map its own properties to the underlying Target properties. Then you can have expressions for different objects by simply by changing Adapter's Target property.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non trivial thing to do as you have it setup. At present, you would basically have to visit each member and value of each expression and then hope to somehow detect or otherwise project that expression to your target.

It is a flawed design.

What is going to make your life eons easier is to simply expose an interface that all of these things share.

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

and then use that on your searchable entites

```
public class Machine : ISearchable {}
public class Part : ISearchable {}
```

and then in your expression constructions

```
IList<Expression<Func<ISearchable,bool>>> list = new List <Expression<Func<ISearchable,bool>>>();

// apply entire list to ISearchable entities
```

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ. I can definitely see how the shared interface would make this easy to reuse across both objects. In fact, I do that in a different scenario. However, in this case the objects do not share the same properties, hence the check for member not existing in the other object. So I'm not sure this would work.

Comment: @jcruz - Perhaps you could expand your example in the question to show why this wont work? There are certainly ways to work through this type of scenario. It depends on what your end goal is. If you want performance, sometimes that requires by type handling unfortunately.